# How to detect touch screen devices and prevent both click and touchstart events from being triggered?

Tags: javascript, touch-event

**The code below is for a drum machine project.**

It's working perfectly on desktop click events are working perfectly, however on touch screen devices (testing on my Iphone) I am getting no sound.
When I go to the chrome dev tools, mobile view. "is touch device" is being logged to the console so it is detecting a touch device but am getting no sound out when using my phone.

```
    const isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in window || 
navigator.maxTouchpoints > 0;
    
    if(!isTouchDevice) {
    console.log("No Touch Device");
        kick.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
            kicksample.currentTime = 0;
            kicksample.play();
        });
    }
    
    if(isTouchDevice) {
    console.log("Is touch device");
        kick.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
            kicksample.currentTime = 0;
            kicksample.play();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```

Comment: So either the touchstart is not being triggered or something else is preventing kicksample from playing.  You can put a console log inside the touchstart listener to narrow it down.